# Help with Chase AI? (Similar to Blue Demon)

Tags: unity, c#, ai, rpg, mecanim

all! I'm working on a chase ai / follow player script, for a 2D project of mine, I'm going for something similar to Blue Demon where an integer value controls what enemy is on screen, and can be changed for individual instances, and it follows the players animations and directions closely, and when you make contact with the enemy, you are defeated- game over. Anyways, I've got some code 'somewhat' working, i have an enumeration that controls the state machine of the animator, however, The Update loop is the real problem here, as of right now-

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

```
    //bool isMoving = anim.GetBool("isMoving"); 
    if (EnemyID == 0)
    {
        //transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(self.position, player.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position) <= maxRange && Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position)>= minRange)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isMoving", true);
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        // Enter State
        MovingState();         
    }
    else {
        IdleState();
    }
```

}

Instead of the object following the player, it starts to run away when the player gets near? or when the player goes to a corner, it moves diagonally? It never seems to actually follow the player consistently. Suggestions and constructive criticism are greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
    Animator anim;
    bool caught;
    public Animator player;
    public Transform target;
    [SerializeField]
    float speed = 5f;
    [SerializeField]
    float maxRange;
    [SerializeField]
    float minRange;

    public int EnemyID;
    State state;
```

The EnemyID as of now isn't necessarily set to a specific value (i.e, it is set to 0) When it is equal to that number, the Update loop is supposed to have the object follow the player at a specific speed and range, during this time, the anim reference is setting the animator boolean parameter 'isMoving' to true starting the walking animation.  If the enemy object stops moving, it should enter its idle state.

```
    IEnumerator IdleState()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        anim.Play("Idle");
    }

    IEnumerator MovingState()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        anim.Play("Move");
    }
```

Currently the idle state is not working, but this is alright.

Comment: You might want to show us the code in MovingState too, and show us how your EnemyID, speed, and target variables get assigned.

Comment: ` Animator anim;
    bool caught;
    public Animator player;
    public Transform target;
    [SerializeField]
    float speed = 5f;
    [SerializeField]
    float maxRange;
    [SerializeField]
    float minRange;

    public int EnemyID;
    State state; `

Comment: You can edit your question to include a more complete code sample. Important information like that shouldn't be just in a comment.

Comment: Ah, fair point, doing that rn.

Comment: Edited the post to include this information.

Comment: Just checking in, any ideas?

Comment: Is it configured to move with its animation? (I know this is supposed to be doable but I have not managed to get it working yet). I am thinking that effect might kick in outside [min,max].

Comment: @Emil Just saw this now, sorry! I'm not entirely certain what you are meaning, but in the code, whenever the object starts to move, it transitions in the aninator to its moving state by setting the isMoving boolean to true, i've managed to fix some of our main problen, in regards to a lack of proper movement, now it follows me like a young child might follow their mother; rather close behind. Struggling to get it to be a specific distance away initially, and not constantly be directly on top of the player right now, I can send samples later if it helps, I am away from home right now.

Comment: Back home, if you have any ideas, please let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: Update! It all works now thanks to setting the speed variable to exactly half of the players speed, might tweak a bit later, but it works as intended, thanks for your help! :3